# 10 digit mt_rand() with unbiased first digit

Tags: php, random

I want to generate the profile ids in my software. The `mt_rand` function works well but I need the ids to be a fixed 10 digit long. Currently I am looping through `mt_rand` outputs until I get a 10 digit number. But the problem I am facing now is that most of the profile ids start from 1 and some from 2. None from any of the other single digit numbers. I understand this happens because of `mt_rand`'s range and it can't produce 10 digit numbers that start with 3 or more.

This is what I am currently doing

```
for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++){
    $num = mt_rand();
    if(strlen($num) == 10) echo $num."<br>";
}
```

If you run the above code you will see all numbers start from either 1 or 2. Any way to fix this?

Edit: I guess I can just flip the numbers but some numbers end with zero and this seems like a bit of a hack anyways. But then again, random number generation is a hack in itself I guess.

Comment: `mt_rand(1,9) . mt_rand(1, 9). ...10x` ?!

Comment: If we are going down that path then how about `mt_rand(1,9) . mt_rand(100000000, 999999999)`?

Comment: Yup, I am the OP :P. This feels like a neat idea actually. I guess if nothing better comes up I will go with this. It's a bit of a hack but it should do the job.

Comment: `echo mt_getrandmax (); // 2147483647` - this answr for you why

Comment: Yup, `mt_rand`'s max is a 10 digit number that starts with 2 so that means no 10 digit number that starts with anything more.

Comment: Depends on your PHP installation. 64-bit or 32-bit...

Comment: The notes on the [php page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php) suggest they both return the same number. Strange. I don't have access to a 32 bit system to confirm.

Comment: @Rizier123 *On both 32 and 64-bit systems (OS X and Linux), mt_getrandmax() returns 2147483647 for me, i.e. ~2^31.* - from php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just start your IDs at 1000000001 , then ID 2 at 1000000002 , ID 543 at 1000000543 , and so on?

alternatively, keep calling mt_rand(1000000001,min((PHP_INT_SIZE>4 ? intval("9999999999",10): PHP_INT_MAX),mt_getrandmax())) until you get an ID which does not already exist in your database? (this will be more and more cpu intesive as your db grows larger and larger.. when its almost full, i wouldn't be surprised if it took billions of iterations and several minutes..)

Comment: I was avoiding having sequential ids to make it a little difficult to scrape the data off the site. And about the second option, I was of the opinion that we can't have a min or max greater than the function's range but after reading the manual page again I realize I was wrong so the second option is perfectly valid. Thanks!

Comment: well, in 32bit PHP, you'll need to use mt_rand(1000000001,2147483648) , and in 64bit PHP you can use mt_rand(1000000001,9999999999)... if you need higher numbers in 32bit PHP, you could resort to GMP or some bignum lib =/

Comment: > Returns the maximum random value returned by a call to mt_rand() without arguments, which is the maximum value that can be used for its max parameter without the result being scaled up (and therefore less random).

[mt_getrandmax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php) So this suggests that it should work even on the 32 bit systems, it would just not be as random. Which is something I can afford.

Comment: "when its almost full" lol that's like a billion users. If my code has even a tenth as many users then random id generation would be the least of my worries. Haha.

Comment: hah, good point  (and actually it'd be like 10 billion users  :D )

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Rizier's suggestion, the only way to ensure any string (even a string of numbers) fits a given mold for length and rules is to generate it one character at a time and then fit them together

```
$str = '';
for($loop = 0; $loop < 10; $loop++) {
    $str .= mt_rand(0,9);
}
echo $str;
```

You can then add rules to this. Maybe you don't want a leading 0 so you can add a rule for that. Maybe you want letters too. This will always give you a random string with the rules you want.

You can see this in action here http://3v4l.org/kIRdV

Comment: This does add an added layer of complexity to the code. Some of the other options are one liners like `mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999)` like @hanshenrik suggested.

Comment: @Achshar True, but this avoids any and all bias

Comment: That's correct. The manual says giving range bigger than the max possible output results in less random output. So for a purist this would be the best option. Luckily for me I am not doing cryptography :P